# Python try except finally: Invalid syntax error (what's wrong with this code?)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use finally in the following function, however, Python reports a Syntax error. I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but I can't seem to spot it ...

Snippet follows below:

```
# Store ids with key
# Returns GUID (used to clear table after words)
def storeIdsInTemporaryTable(dbinfo, id_list):
    conn = dbinfo['db_connection']

    guid = genutils.getGUID()
    orig_tableinfo = dbinfo['table']
    orig_datarows = dbinfo['datarows']

    metadata = dbinfo['metadata']

    sql = "INSERT INTO temporary_data_key (key) VALUES ({0}) RETURNING id".format(guid)
    key_id = executeSQLonDbConnection(dbinfo, sql, return_field='id')

    tableinfo = Table('temporary_data', metadata, autoload=True)
    datarows = []

    for id_value in id_list:
        datarows.append( { 'key_id': key_id, 'id_value': id_value} )

    try:
        insertToDb(dbinfo)
    except:
        guid = None # to indicate an error occured
        if key_id:
            conn.execute("DELETE FROM temporary_data_key WHERE key={0}".format(guid)

    finally:
        dbinfo['table'] = orig_tableinfo
        dbinfo['datarows'] = orig_datarows

    return guid
```

What is causing the syntax error?

As an aside, I am aware that I need to wrap the two inserts in a transaction, but for some reason, I can't get transactions to work (SQLALchemy throws a transaction related error) - so thats for another question another time..

**[[Edit]]**

The exception error (now fixed) was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/script.py", line 1632
    finally:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you post the exception as well please?

Comment: @vartec CodeReview is for improving efficiency/style/etc of working code - OP has a SyntaxError, making it belong firmly here.

Comment: @lvc: it sure doesn't belong here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87164/147630

Comment: @vartec I'll take the point that says syntax error questions should be closed and possibly deleted as 'too trivial'. But that is a far step from 'belongs on CodeReview'. Of all *.SE, it fits here the closest - even if it does or should get closed, here was the best (or at least the least worst) place for the OP to ask it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in your call to `execute()`. It should be:

```
conn.execute("DELETE FROM temporary_data_key WHERE key={0}".format(guid))
```

Instead of:

```
conn.execute("DELETE FROM temporary_data_key WHERE key={0}".format(guid)
```

Answer (score 17):

Are you using a Python < 2.5? try except finally was only added in 2.5 and before you had to wrap try except in a try finally.